# How do you migrate C# into a webpart for SharePoint 2010-My Site?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

How do you add a webpart to 'My Site' that was created using C# in Visual Studio 2010, while SharePoint sites on SQL 2008?

Comment: can you precise your question, do you have any problem ?

Comment: You will need to clarify what you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this using code if match your request http://www.etechplanet.com/blog/addingremoving-web-part-programmatically-in-sharepoint-website-using-c-code.aspx

Comment: @Silx- Thank you. I had gone to the site and noticed that you can add form web parts, but they are only for 'HTML Form Web Parts' and 'InfoPath Form Web Parts'. What I am trying to add is a program that I created that obtains the user vacation hours from the database and how much time they have left to use and how many hours they had already used. This was created in C#/ASP.NET and I don't see how I can add that to the page. I have selected 'Upload a Web Part' which is located under 'Categories' and after I select browse and choose what I want to upload, then I receive an 'Error' Page.

Comment: Now I just lost 'My Content' page.

Comment: Sorry about that, I retrieved my page. Can I add my own webpart to a page or does it have to be HTML or InfoPath? If so, how can I do this? I'm still learning how to work with the code and even inserting the code from the link, where would I put it in my code?